# In Gatsby how to render React Icons dynamically from gatsby-config's menuLinks?

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, menu, gatsby, react-icons

Following Gatsby's doc on [Creating Dynamic Navigation in Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-dynamic-navigation/) I created a barebones menu and wanted to see if I can add [React Icons'](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/) components to it:

*gatsby-config.js* (stripped down)

```
menuLinks:[
  {
      name:'home',
      icon: 'AiFillHome',
      link:'/'
  },
  {
      name:'contact',
      icon: 'AiFillHome',
      link:'/contact'
  }
]
```

after finding out that Gatsby errors out when I tried creating an external `menuLinks` file as a module, example:

failed approach as module:

```
import React from 'react'

// React Icons
import { AiFillHome } from 'react-icons/ai'

const Menu = [
  {
      name:'home',
      icon: <AiFillHome />,
      link:'/'
  },
  {
      name:'contact',
      icon: <AiFillHome />,
      link:'/contact'
  }
]

export default Menu
```

I dont have an issue in my query:

```
const data = useStaticQuery(
  graphql`
    query {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          menuLinks {
            name
            icon
            link
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `,
)
```

in a file I've passed down menu props to from my query and then map.

(stripped down file):

```
{menu.map((menuItem, key) => {
    return (
      <Link key={key} to={menuItem.link}>
        <div>
          <span className="icon">{`<${menuItem.icon} />`}</span>
          {menuItem.name}
        </div>
      </Link>
    )
})}
```

my `icon` doesn't render. I've also tried:

```
<span className="icon" component={menuItem.icon} />
```

doesn't work. I've also tried:

```
<span className="icon"><menuItem.icon /></span>
```

and:

```
<span className="icon">{React.createElement(menuItem.icon)}</span>
```

Research:

- [Making an HTML string from a React component in background, how to use the string by dangerouslySetInnerHTML in another React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567329/making-an-html-string-from-a-react-component-in-background-how-to-use-the-strin)
- [React render components from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520714/react-render-components-from-string)
- [How to render string as custom React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60241137/how-to-render-string-as-custom-react-component)
- [React / JSX Dynamic Component Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name)

In Gatsby how can I pass an icon's component name to `menuLinks` and later render it?

### Edit

After the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71702133/1952287) the implementation of:

```
{menu.map(({link, name, icon: Icon}) => {
    return (
      <Link key={name} to={link}>
        <div>
          <span className="icon"><Icon /></span>
          {name}
        </div>
      </Link>
    )
})}
```

the browser doesn't render the React Icon Component and when examining the Elements panel I get:

```
<span class="icon">
  <aifillhome></aifillhome>
</span>
```

Also note I do get a terminal error of:

> warning  'AiFillHome' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

which was expected but that leads to me wondering how do I bring in:

```
import { AiFillHome } from 'react-icons/ai'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation of:

```
const AssetComponentsTuple = new Map([
  [`home`, <AiFillHome />],
  [`otherAsset`, <AiFillHome2 />],
])

export default AssetComponentsTuple
```

would throw an error of:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

but the approach gave me an idea for this workaround of:

```
{menu.map(({link, name, icon}) => {
    return (
      <Link key={name} to={link}>
        <div>
          <span className="icon"><IconRetrieve icon={icon} /></span>
          {name}
        </div>
      </Link>
    )
})}
```

and that allowed me to pass the icon string and ternary for the component.

`IconRetrieve` component:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

// React Icons
import { AiFillHome } from 'react-icons/ai'
import { MdCall } from 'react-icons/md'
import { BiErrorCircle } from 'react-icons/bi'

const IconRetrieve = ({ icon }) => {
  const mapIcons = new Map([
    [`home`, <AiFillHome />],
    [`contact`, <MdCall />],
    [`default`, <BiErrorCircle />],
  ])
  return mapIcons.has(icon) ? mapIcons.get(icon) : mapIcons.get('default')
}

IconRetrieve.propTypes = {
  icon: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

export default IconRetrieve
```

The positive of this approach is I can create SVG components or any component in that matter and return it based on the icon string.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
{menu.map(({link, name, icon: Icon}) => {
    return (
      <Link key={name} to={link}>
        <div>
          <span className="icon"><Icon /></span>
          {name}
        </div>
      </Link>
    )
})}
```

Since you are looping through the `menu` elements, `icon` is not interpreted as a React element because of the capitalization. In the destructuring above you are parsing `icon` as `Icon` so rendering it as a React component in `<Icon />` should do the trick because it's the element itself.

There's another workaround that seems a little bit overkill but will work: you can always use a `Map` to hold the asset component, something like:

```
const AssetComponentsTuple = new Map([
  [`home`, <AiFillHome />],
  [`otherAsset`, <AiFillHome2 />],
]);

export default AssetComponentsTuple;
```

Your menu will become:

```
const Menu = [
  {
      name:'home',
      icon: 'home',
      link:'/'
  },
  {
      name:'contact',
      icon: 'otherAsset',
      link:'/contact'
  }
]
```

Then in the loop:

```
{menu.map(({link, name, icon}) => {
   let IconComponent = AssetComponentsTuple.get(icon);
    return (
      <Link key={name} to={link}>
        <div>
          <span className="icon"><IconComponent /></span>
          {name}
        </div>
      </Link>
    )
})}
```

You can even get rid of `icon` property and use directly the `name` in the `AssetComponentsTuple`, in that case: `AssetComponentsTuple.get(name)`

Comment: That's closer but it doesn't render in the browser still. Made an edit with the details.

Comment: Hmm... what about `{React.createElement(Icon)}`

Comment: same rendered result of `<aifillhome></aifillhome>`

Comment: I've added a `Map` workaround while I try to find another way :/

Comment: the `Map` wasn't working for me but gave me an idea to create a component solution so +1 and as always a pleasure talking Gatsby with you.